# validate number with regular exp in javascript not working for one case

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to validate a number field integer and decimal with regular exp. its working fine for all the cases except one digit number:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#quantity").on('blur',function(){
        var quantity = $('#quantity').val() 
        var pattern = /^-?\d+\.?([0-9]{1,2})$/;
        alert(pattern.test(quantity))
    })
})
```

output:

```
1 ---> false (why?)
-
9 ---> false (why?)
5.87 -->true (fine)
12.35 ---> true  (fine)
12.344 --->false (fine)
2323.34 --->true (fine)
```

for 1 to 9 its alerting `True` but i need it as `false`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have both `\d+` and `[0-9]{1,2}` in the string, which implies there must be at least 2 digits in the string (with an optional decimal in between).

If you want the entire decimal part to be optional, just surround it with parentheses and add a `?` quantifier:

```
/^-?\d+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

Comment: then how can i write it? for integer it will return true and decimal it will take upto 2 digit after point?

Comment: dude need one more help plz.. now its working for negetive number i want to stop it. like for -3 it should return false

Comment: You'll need to use lookaround assertions (http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)